# Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported when mysql.connector is imported

Tags: python, mysql

I am using jupyter notebook (MacOS, anaconda distribution version 1.9.0, Python 3.9.7). When I try to connect MySQL, I get an error **NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported**. The package I installed was *!pip install mysql.connector* .

Later I uninstall **mysql.connector** and installed **!pip install mysql-connector-python**. This time it worked. I am importing **import mysql.connector** for both the cases.

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
host='localhost', 
user='root', 
password='12345'
)
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: That package is outdated,try `mysql-connector-python`!

Comment: Thanks for the information!